# Nativescript sidekick error during cloud build

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am getting a strange error from sidekick cloud build since a few hours ago.

I was building the app successfully, but all of a sudden, it gives me the following error and even reversing the changes does not fix anything. I have even tried with a fully working version of my git repo.

```
[19-01-28 16:55:27.709] Build step started.
[19-01-28 16:55:37.465] (CLI) Unable to apply changes on device: a754d27bafb8bb273e444b9d6cefd370cd55f4d4. Error is: Build failed..
[19-01-28 16:55:37.469] Error detected during LiveSync on a754d27bafb8bb273e444b9d6cefd370cd55f4d4 for C:\Users\Afshar\Desktop\myapp. Error: Build failed.
```

I doesn't give me any more details about the issue.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get more logs in cloud build or if this is a known issue?

Thanks

Comment: Usually a clean build fixes the error for me. I happens once in a while, so I didn't bother to check why it happens. If it's still an issue, try resetting the simulator once.

Comment: I am running on a real device. It was working and suddenly the error appeared. I tried clean build, rebooting system!, reboot iphone!, connecting using a different port! and none of them worked
I am not even sure if it is an issue with my phone or with cloud build servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it.
In case anyone else faces this issue, I tried the following command using a hint on this page and it solved the problem.
https://docs.nativescript.org/troubleshooting

```
tns platform remove ios
```

and then, I was able to build the project in sidekick.

Answer (score 0):

It happens with me as well for reasons unknown. I couldn't find any root cause, but I did notice one pattern. It usually happens when I am already running the app on an Android Emulator/Device.

When we execute `tns run android --bundle`, it listens for file changes after the first build and does some webpack incremental build thing afterwards, right?

At the same time, once Sidekick delivers a successful iOS build, it also starts listening for changes to do the webpack incremental builds on iOS.

So while we have these two `LISTENERS` active and we request for another iOS cloud build, before Sidekick communicates with the cloud, it **modifies some files** which the `android listener` detects and results in an `incremental android build`, which in turn **modifies some other files**, which the `iOS listener` detects, resulting in Sidekick trying to do the `incremental iOS build` but this time its stuck between giving you the incremental update and the new requested cloud build, so it throws you this `LiveSync` error.

Moral of the story: Try to request cloud builds, when these `listeners` are inactive.

Comment: Thanks for response, the error was actually about the build itself, not the livesync and the live sync was misleading. This error was happening even on publish and build (not run).
Finally I was able to solve it using 'tns platform remove ios' and building again